# Wrong expansion for the variable "$?" in makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

***From the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#Automatic-Variables):***

> `$?`
>   
>   
>   The names of all the prerequisites that are newer than the target,
>   with spaces between them.

***Now, given a makefile:***

```make
# Create target 'all', that is created later than 'old', which was created after 'older'.
$(shell touch older)
$(shell sleep 1)
$(shell touch old)
$(shell sleep 1)
$(shell touch all)

all : old phony;
    @echo '"$$?" is: "$?"'

# A command to turn the file 'old' even "older", by acquiring the modification-time of 'older'.
old ::
    cp -p 'older' 'old'


.PHONY: phony
```

***Running, I get:***

```console
$ make
cp -p 'older' 'old'
"$?" is: "old phony"

# Trying again, but this time, with a *parallel-execution*.
$ make -j
cp -p 'older' 'old'
"$?" is: "phony"
```

***Can you see, that Make expand the value of `$?` differently for a *parallel execution* (`-j`), than it does for a *non-parallel-execution*?***


Let's first analyze the first case, i.e. for a **non-parallel** execution.

The modification-time of `all` and `old` are:

- ***Before the build***, `old` was "older" than `all`. This is self-evident. Right?
- ***After Make finished building the prerequisite***, i.e. after Make "builds" `old`, `old` got "older", so to speak, by "acquiring" the modification time of a file named: `older`. This is basically a net-result of the shell command: `cp -p older old`. Now, it is not hard to see, that `older` was **way** "older" than `all`.

Now, Make ended up building the target `all`, because of the **other** prerequisite, namely: `phony`.

But, according the documentation, `$?` should expands only to "the names of all the prerequisites that are **newer** than the target". This is an **exact** quote.

Could we agree, that `old` was **never** *newer* than `all`. And, if fact, had it not been for `phony`, Make would not even re-build `all`.

So, how wrong is it then, for Make, to expand `$?` to `old phony`.

`phony` I get. But `old`? Really?!

But, let's now turn our attention to parallel-execution, where Make expands `$?` as `phony`.

Here:

1. Certainly, one can say, that **this** expansion is right (compared to the expansion in a *non-parallel* execution).
   The reason is, that only `phony` ***is*** the file that triggered the re-build of `all`. Without it, Make would not bother to re-build `all`, at-all.
2. Still, one wonders, how can make expand the variable differently for a these two modes of execution.
   I can not even think, how this could be any relevant to the expansion of `$?`.


   In summary, it looks like that a "random" change (i.e. a modification in the mode of execution, from a *parallel* to a *non-parallel*) influences a seemingly unrelated entity, that is the expansion of *automatic-variables*. Why?

Comment: I just posted an answer to the linked question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32131796/258523) that I believe answers this question as well.

Answer (score 1):

Having built `old` using the rules, Make now considers that to be the newest file in the dependency graph.  It **does not inspect `old` after making it**.

This is obviously the right thing to do for phony targets, and it usually is The Right Thing for file targets, too.

Comment: 1) Technically, Make "inspects" `old` after re-building it. And had it not been for `phony`, Make would not re-build `all`. Furthermore, you can try a makefile like `all: new`, where prior to a build, `new` is newer than `all`, an if Make re-builds `new` by modifying its modification-time to one **older** than `all`, make will **not** build `all`. In other words, Make inspect its time (of the dependency) **after** its build, and **only** if it is **then** newer that the `target`, then and only then, will Make re-build the `target`.

Comment: 2) If you modify the Makefile, where Make does not really change the modification time, but runs some random command, or perhaps a command to copy (and preserving its mode) a file that happens to have the exact same modification time, then Make will not expand `$?` to `old`.

Comment: 3) Even in the above case, if you happen to run in *parallel-mode* (`-j`), Make will not expand to `old`. So, clearly something is wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Any file built or updated by make has been updated, so it will implicitly assume it to be newer, even if you hack in a command that makes it older.

Theoretically, Make should work on the contents of a file, not the date. If the contents are different, then you should run dependent builds. Given that we don't have filesystems providing easy content-derivates (hashes or such) it uses the last-modified-date to do this. As that's also not 100% reliable - see for example systems on which those dates don't have sufficient accuracy or may be *just* in the future - it'll also use this as an information source. If it just built it, it must be modified, therefore it's correct to consider it "newer" or "rebuilt".

Comment: _Any file built or updated by make has been updated, so it will implicitly assume it to be newer_ No actually. _make_ definitely checks the file time of a real target after running the target's recipe. Not for .PHONY targets of course — they are always out of date. This explains the (very useful) difference between `.PHONY: target` and `target: FORCE`