# Inconsistent expansion by make for the '$?' variable

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

***From the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#Automatic-Variables):***

> `$?`
>   
>   
>        The names of all the prerequisites that are newer than the target,
>        with spaces between them.

***So, given a makefile:***

```make
# Force make to search for 'foo' in the VPATH directory
$(shell rm -rf foo)
# If 'D' is a "regular" file, we remove it first.
$(shell rm -rf D)
$(shell mkdir D)
# Suggest a VPATH-file, for Make to "associate" with 'foo'.
$(shell touch D/foo)
$(shell sleep 1)
# Target 'all' is newer than prerequisite 'D/foo'
$(shell touch all)

VPATH = D

all : foo phony
    echo '$?'

foo ::
    touch '$@'

.PHONY: phony

.PRECIOUS : D/foo
```

***And running, I get:***

```console
$ make -r
touch 'D/foo'
echo 'D/foo phony'
D/foo phony

# Try again, but this time, with parallel-execution mode.
$ make -r -j
touch 'D/foo'
echo 'phony'
phony
```

Here, we have 2 serious issues:

1. Given the simple and **explicit** recipe to "touch" the prerequisite `foo`, which Make clearly executes - hence will **guarantee** that `foo` will be "newer" than `all` - Make still does **not** expand `$?` to `D/foo`, at-least in the 2nd case above (i.e. for the *parallel*-execution (`-j`) mode). Why?
2. If you come up with an explanation for the above, shouldn't it also explain, why in the 1st case (*non-parallel* execution), `$?` - **does** indeed - get expanded to `D/foo`.


   I guess, I had an assumption, that *parallel* vs. *non-parallel* aside, Make will **always** pause before executing a target, and **first** check if **all** of its prerequisites had already **finished** their respective builds.

So, shouldn't the `$?` variable be identically expanded for both cases?

Comment: Observation: I don't like the way you are writing your makefiles.  I've seen a number of your questions, and I've not answered any of them, in part on those grounds (and in part because the `make` I use most frequently won't run the makefiles).  The `$(shell …)` material grates on me (or is the principal source of concern).  OTOH, I'm just an old fuddy-duddy, so you don't have to pay attention, but … I'm not keen on the notation you're using.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've wondered about that myself. I've mostly convinced myself that's just a way to make them self-contained but I'm not sure. I also think, at least in some cases that might affect things, but I just pulled it out of this test and it didn't. Though my results aren't consistent for the non-`-j` case in that I don't always get `D/foo` listed there either. And with make 3.81 I don't see `phony` in that list at all.

Comment: Ohh! Makefile syntax is notorious for its beauty and readability. NOT!

And this is the only syntax that Make provides to communicate with the shell. Is it nice? NOT! Is it reliable? NOT! Is there a way to check for erros from the shell? Mostly not!

But, there is no other consistent way, to guarantee a reproduction of bugs in makefile, unless you embed those lines, and "hope" for the best.

Comment: You don't need to use only the makefile for this. A tiny wrapper shell script works just fine too. It isn't as if you get points for saving space.

Comment: Have you tried changing the `sleep 0.1` to `sleep 10` (or, more sensibly, `sleep 2`).  I wonder if sub-second granularity is part of the problem.

Comment: I note that there is a [tag:gnu-make] tag.  I suggest using it — unless you think this is meant to be portable to other versions of `make`.  It then characterizes things squarely; people can provide the GNU `make` answer without worrying about which other versions of `make` they should be considering.

Comment: How is this question different from your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32114743/258523) from a few hours ago?

Comment: @Etan_Reisner IMHO, over there, *parallel* gets it right, and here, *non-parallel* gets it right. They "smack" also of two different bugs. Just a feeling.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two issues going on here.

The first is that double-colon rules appear to act like phony targets in that they force make to consider the target as "newer" regardless of actual modification time. (This is why the non-parallel version behaves the way it does. Change from `foo ::` to `foo :` and you don't get `foo` in the `$?` output at all.)

The second thing is that, despite that, using parallel mode seems to force make back into considering modification times of its prerequisites (so the previous behavior is avoided).

This is conjecture and not definitive since I haven't dug through the code to see if this is actually happening but it explains the results here (it also explains the results on the other, nearly identical, question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32114743/258523)).

Comment: As for my [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32114743/wrong-expansion-for-the-variable-in-makefile) there, you get **identical** results for `old` with a **single**-colon. Just make sure that Make executes the recipe for `old`, by either 1) Removing `old` before **each** build, or 2) Adding `phony` as a prerequisite to `old`.